# Magento 2 Page builder product attribute cannot render html

Tags: magento2, php, phtml

In Magento 2.4.3 I have created a page builder product attribute labeled "Before Content" which the admin will populate with html and I want to show in product page. Under child theme I have created Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/before-content.phtml

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();
if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'custom') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}
$_attributeValue = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
?>

<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
    <div class="before-content" <?php  echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>>
        <?php echo $_attributeValue; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In the catalog_product_view.xml I have added the following:

```
<move element="before-content" destination="info_wrap" before="product.info.details"/><referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="before-content" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/before-content.phtml" group="detailed_info">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getBeforeContent</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">before_content</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">before-content</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">before_content</argument>
        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="before_content"</argument>
        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Before content</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Using the following variable in before-content.html returns "escaped" (plain text) result and not rendered html.

```
$_attributeValue = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

How can I render the html in product page?

Comment: Not a single person?

Comment: did you found the answer to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->get@attribute_code(), '@attribute_code'); ?>
```